# Failing to set up plutus on windows

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

So I'm using WSL Windows 10 and I set up IOHK hashes, but everytime I run `nix-shell` I get following error:
`build of '/nix/store/9im4jp068ykqsm4s8996px605p6zrw7q-Agda-plan-to-nix-pkgs.drv' failed`. Would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by upgrading to wsl 2.